# Having multiple window.onload functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload

I am having to use multiple `window.onload` functions on one page because the JS plugin that I am using is calling the `window.onload` function already. I would like to not edit the plugin and work around it. Here is what I have tried:

```
<div id="Count"></div>

//<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js" /> // JS plugin using window.onload

var INCREMENT = 3;
var count = 0;
var msInterval = 800;
var oldonload = window.onload; // assigning current window.onload to a variable

window.onload = function() { <-- error line
  if (oldonload) {
    oldonload();
  }
  document.getElementById('Count').innerHTML = count;
  setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('Count').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```
function myFunction() {
    // do stuff here
}
window.addEventListener("load", myFunction, false);
```

Comment: That works... but I guess I am still curious as to what I did wrong with what I tried. Do you have any idea what it may be?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps it's because you're missing a semicolon at the end of your code snippet.